# Connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017 in Mongodb

Tags: node.js, node-mongodb-native

Hello I am new to MongoDB. I am trying to Connect to MongoDb with `'mongodb://localhost:27017'` but not connecting. However I try to enter with MongoDb Compass and mongosh shell command it is working.
The error codes are

> ```
> node app.js
> node:internal/process/promises:288
> triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
>             ^
>
> AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: null == MongoServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
> at Timeout._onTimeout (C:\Users\kokophone\Documents\MEGAsync\Mystudy\Web\Udemy\Angela Bootcamp\Mgphone One\MangoDB\FruitProject\node_modules\mongodb\lib\sdam\topology.js:292:38)
> at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:564:17)
> at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:507:7) {
> [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(0) {},
> code: undefined,
> reason: TopologyDescription {
> commonWireVersion: 0,
> compatible: true,
> heartbeatFrequencyM...
> at C:\Users\kokophone\Documents\MEGAsync\Mystudy\Web\Udemy\Angela Bootcamp\Mgphone One\MangoDB\FruitProject\app.js:15:10
> at C:\Users\kokophone\Documents\MEGAsync\Mystudy\Web\Udemy\Angela Bootcamp\Mgphone One\MangoDB\FruitProject\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:349:66 {
> generatedMessage: true,
> code: 'ERR_ASSERTION',
> actual: null,
> expected: MongoServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
> at Timeout._onTimeout (C:\Users\kokophone\Documents\MEGAsync\Mystudy\Web\Udemy\Angela Bootcamp\Mgphone One\MangoDB\FruitProject\node_modules\mongodb\lib\sdam\topology.js:292:38)
> at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:564:17)
> at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:507:7) {
> reason: TopologyDescription {
> type: 'Unknown',
> servers: Map(1) {
>         'localhost:27017' => ServerDescription {
> address: 'localhost:27017',
> type: 'Unknown',
> hosts: [],
> passives: [],
> arbiters: [],
> tags: {},
> minWireVersion: 0,
> maxWireVersion: 0,
> roundTripTime: -1,
> lastUpdateTime: 2313988,
> lastWriteDate: 0,
> error: MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
> at connectionFailureError (C:\Users\kokophone\Documents\MEGAsync\Mystudy\Web\Udemy\Angela Bootcamp\Mgphone One\MangoDB\FruitProject\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connect.js:387:20)
> at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\kokophone\Documents\MEGAsync\Mystudy\Web\Udemy\Angela Bootcamp\Mgphone One\MangoDB\FruitProject\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connect.js:310:22)
> at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:628:26)
> at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
> at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
> at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
> at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
> cause: [Error],
> [Symbol(errorLabels)]: [Set]
>           },
> topologyVersion: null,
> setName: null,
> setVersion: null,
> electionId: null,
> logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null,
> primary: null,
> me: null,
>           '$clusterTime': null
>         }
>       },
> stale: false,
> compatible: true,
> heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
> localThresholdMS: 15,
> setName: null,
> maxElectionId: null,
> maxSetVersion: null,
> commonWireVersion: 0,
> logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null
>     },
> code: undefined,
> [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(0) {}
>   },
> operator: '=='
> }
>
> Node.js v18.12.1
> ```

please help me out.

Comment: Is MongoDB bound to the IPv6 loopback address? Perhaps you need to try `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`

Comment: U need to add your ip address in mongodb network access panel.

Comment: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017 use this as connection string.

Answer (score 0):

Change localhost by 0.0.0.0.  in the source code .

const url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/";
const client = new MongoClient(url);

to

const url = "mongodb://0.0.0.0:27017/";
const client = new MongoClient(url);